# How to get all elements where one STRING ARRAY contains ANY of the elements in another STRING ARRAY?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cockroachdb

I have a table with a STRING ARRAY column and I'm trying to get all rows, in which the Array column contains elements from another STRING ARRAY.
F.E:

```
CREATE TABLE a (b STRING[]);
INSERT INTO a VALUES 
(ARRAY['car', 'train', 'boat']), 
(ARRAY['elephant', 'hippo', 'tiger']),
(ARRAY['bear', 'dog', 'cat']);
```

Now I want to get all rows containing at least one of the elements I have in my array.
So far the best option I found was

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE b @> ARRAY['dog'] OR b @> ARRAY['tiger'];
```

This is not very convenient as my array is dynamic, and I'd need to build the query in an awkward way.
I was wondering if there's something I'm missing. Maybe something like:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE b @> ANY(ARRAY['dog', 'tiger']);
```

However I don't seem to be getting it right, nor can I find any info on the topic.

Comment: `&&` operator. Found by *reading the manual*.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Comment: Thanks, @MatBailie!
Honestly, it didn't accrue to me to look at PG docs, as I'm using cockroachdb. And it's not very well described there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was written in the comments but for clarity I'll write it out here:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE b && ARRAY['dog', 'tiger'];
```

or you can write it like this

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE b && '{"dog", "tiger"}';
```